# Spyder 3 (Anaconda) on Ubuntu- How to change working directory to that of terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, spyder, python-idle

I'm using Spyder 3 bundled with Anaconda Python on Ubuntu. Usually with other Python IDEs (like IDLE,...) when i want to work inside a specific folder, I just go to that folder then open a terminal, type "idle" and the IDE pops up, then I can work inside that folder. 
But with Spyder when i open a terminal, type "spyder" , the Spyder IDE still works at the default directory! How can I change this? Please help me, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change working directory after opening Spyder by typing inside IPython console `cd path/to/working/dir`.

EDIT:

I have found how you can set directory from the command line (from `spyder3 --help`). It is `-w` flag:

```
 spyder3 -w path/to/dir
```

or

```
cd path/to/dir
spyder3 -w `pwd`
```

Comment: Can't Spyder automatically change working directory to be the same as that of the terminal? You know, because Spyder is opened from the Terminal....

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I showed you the solution that I use.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can really enjoy Spyder to its fullest :D

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The options to configure the current working directory are present in

`Tools > Preferences > Current working directory`.

We don't have a **graphical** way to sync that with the directory of the terminal from which Spyder was started, but there's a command line option to do it, as @Bartłomiej mentioned.

Comment: Your answer conflicts with that of Bartlomiej's (which I have found to be correct). But how could it be when you're one of Spyder's maintainers ?

Comment: Upsy, I forgot about our `-w` command line option, sorry, I never use it. I'll update my answer to mention that there's no **graphical** option to do what you want.